# Why is my logging messed up (socket, thread, signal)?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, signals, pyside

The log output of my python program (using the builtin logging module, but occurs even when using simple prints) is partially messed up, as you can see in the following image. Note the first line, first word still being correct and then it gets mixed up:

[image: logging mess]

I tried to visualize the situation where this happens:

[image: situation]

Basically in my main thread/program I start a simple socketserver.TCPServer to listen for incoming messages. That server runs on its own thread (QtCore.QThread) so my program is not blocked. If some other application sends a message the request handler of the TCPServer will simply forward the message to the main thread using a QtCore.SIGNAL like:

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('received(const QString)'), receivedMessage)
```

The program then does some parsing and computation with that message and logs those, thereby producing the gibberish seen above. At some point the logging returns back to working normally.

I am not sure if this is related to sockets or threading or both, but I guess it may be a common issue and therefore I am thankful for any hints why this occurs.

Comment: Maybe some control characters lurking around ? Could you _redirect_ the output to a file and provide an hexdump of the data.

Comment: I tried redirecting it before posting this question, this works and produces the expected result, so it just seems to get mixed up in the stdout as it kind of mixes two streams or whatever. What is a hexdump :O? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Do you run multiple listerner threads in parallel trying to signal the main thrread?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have located the problem:

When the external application wants to send a message it will always create a new client socket, connect to the server, send the message and then close the client socket.

The `sock.close()` does not seem to close immediately, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) say I should call `sock.shutdown(how)` first, but unfortunately this did not help as well. I can use a small `time.sleep(0.5)` after the close to fix the logging issue, but instead I did something like this:

```
def ensure_closed(self):
    while True:
        try:
            self.sock.recv(1024)
        except:
            break

def close_connection(self):
    self.sock.close()
    self.ensure_closed()

    # Continue with other stuff.
    # Now the logging behaves normally.
```

There might be better ways to do it.

Comment: This is *not* a forum. If you have fixed/narrowed your issue, but still need some help, please *ask an other question*.

Comment: I will not open a new thread for every single question that pops up related to the original one. I have fixed the issue, but still not really answered my original question about why it happens. It obviously is related to closing the socket, but I still don't understand why.